# Layout & Functionality is broken after uploading to web server due to config.js file

Tags: php, jquery, css, html

I developed a small site .After I upload my design with doing some coding and functionality it ,on my hosting company web server layout is broken in all the browsers. I mean Some css is loaded properly but some elements and css are not at their places. I checked several times the css files on my local pc and the webserver and they have same content.
I find this error might be happen dueto my config.js file , i have loaded my css through my config.js file.
here is my website link :[uploaded link](http://cutting-edge.bluecoresys.com/)

It should be displayed and function like this :[proper layout link](http://cutting-edge.bluecoresys.com/design/)

i found this error on my console

```
SyntaxError: syntax error   
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

when i remove this i found error in my head tag when i remove it shows error on body tag and same things is going on.
any body have idea why this thing happen & how to resolve this ?

Comment: what are html tags doing inside a `.js` file?

Comment: i have uploaded styles from my js file . i did same thing in my design also [link](http://cutting-edge.bluecoresys.com/design/) but there iss no problem ?

Comment: No you didn't. In the working link there is no config.js file. There is a configg.js file and that one has no html inside it

Comment: i did it but some problem is also there like my layout broken little bit ,canvas is not there etc link http://cutting-edge.bluecoresys.com

Comment: if i add /index.php then all things is working properly but there is no any index.html file in my directory. i maen http://cutting-edge.bluecoresys.com/index.php is working but http://cutting-edge.bluecoresys.com is not working how ?

Comment: "cutting-edge.bluecoresys.com/index.php is working but cutting-edge.bluecoresys.com is not working"

sounds like .htaccess dealing with some issue!

Comment: Finally got the answer there is config problem due to my config.js file. here is the Working Link cutting-edge.bluecoresys.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

change in

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel-noscript.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-desktop.css" />
```

Comment: i did this also but no effect !

Comment: k i will check not a prob

Comment: you not apply i see your link changes are not appear in view source

Comment: see attached image in this you can see it works i think you forget something

Comment: i did it but some problem is also there like my layout broken little bit ,canvas is not there etc link http://http://cutting-edge.bluecoresys.com/

Comment: Finally got the answer there is config problem due to my config.js file. here is the Working Link cutting-edge.bluecoresys.com

Answer (score 0):

I guess head section of your home page/index file is different than inner page head section. Simplest way will be copy inner page header and paste is in index file. Then do necessary changes in it.

Please insure that all files are in one folder otherwise you have to be more careful with path.

Right now! no script nor stylesheets are getting loaded on your homepage.

Comment: my path is correct i have checked it on local server it work fine but on server there are some problem but not related to path ?

Answer (score 0):

finally got the solution . i removed my config.js file and load all the css directly in my index page.

previously i am loading all css from config.js file with using  this code :

```
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel-noscript.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-desktop.css" />
    </noscript>
```

Now i have removed my config.js and includes all the css directly in my index page rather using `<noscript>` tag

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel-noscript.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-desktop.css" />
```

i really appreciating all of you.